# How to solve another version of Kakuro

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem is, in a table of (h+1)*(w+1),the first row contains w values: a[1] ... a[w] which fill in the 2rd ... (w+1)th column. The first column contains h values: b[1] ... b[h] which fill in the 2rd ... (h+1)th row. sum(a[i]) is equal to sum(b[i]).

The question is to give one possible solution: result, so that sum(result[i][K]) for a certain K, is equal to a[i] with result[i][K] != result[j][K] (i != j and 0 < i < h+1). And the same rule for rows. PS: All the integers are positive.

For example:

```
a[] = {10, 3, 3}, b[] = {9, 7}

 //   10  3  3

 // 9  6  2  1

 // 7  4  1  2

result = {6, 2, 1;
          4, 1, 2}
```

It is like Kakuro but not the same. I cannot figure out which algorithm to apply, if anyone knows how to solve it, please give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your assignment to a is of 11,2,3; however your comment says 10,3,3.  Which is correct?

Comment: Also, can you clarify the requirements.  What do you mean sum(a[i]) is equal to sum(b[i]); and what do you mean by "fill in"

Comment: @MartinBonner Sorry I made a mistake. Now it is OK.

Comment: Right.  So we are given the sums of the rows and the columns, and asked to calculate the table entries.

Comment: @MartinBonner sum(a[i]) is equal to sum(b[i]), in my example, is 10+3+3==9+7. "fill in" means in my example, result fills in the rest of the table. That's just a kind of description. The example can explain all.

Comment: @MartinBonner That's it. And with some restrictions mentioned. Just one possible result is needed.

Comment: Are you sure this can be solved more efficient than with backtracking?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I'm not sure if backtracking will lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: if the problem size is finite then backtracking by definition completes in a finite amount of time, at most it tests all possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always solve your problem with backtracking. Basic idea here: from top-to-bottom and left-to-right try a valid value in the partially filled table, backtrack when this value doesn't lead to a solution.

Minimal example in `C++` with annotated `solve`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

class Problem {
public:
    template<class AIter, class BIter>
    Problem(AIter abegin, AIter aend, BIter bbegin, BIter bend)
    :   m_width(std::distance(abegin, aend))
    ,   m_height(std::distance(bbegin, bend))
    ,   m_table(new int[(m_width + 1) * (m_height + 1)])
    {
        std::fill(m_table.get(), m_table.get() + (m_width + 1) * (m_height + 1), 0);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m_width; ++i)
            m_table[i + 1] = *abegin++;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m_height; ++j)
            m_table[(j + 1) * (m_width + 1)] = *bbegin++;
    }

    bool Solve() { return solve(0, 0); }
    int operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const;

private:
    int a(size_t i) const { return m_table[i + 1]; }
    int b(size_t j) const { return m_table[(j + 1) * (m_width + 1)]; }
    int get(size_t i, size_t j) const { return m_table[(j + 1) * (m_width + 1) + i + 1]; }
    void set(size_t i, size_t j, int value) { m_table[(j + 1) * (m_width + 1) + i + 1] = value; }
    int colSum(size_t i) const;
    int rowSum(size_t j) const;
    bool solve(size_t i, size_t j);

    size_t m_width, m_height;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> m_table; // (width + 1) x (height + 1)
};

int Problem::colSum(size_t i) const {
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m_height; ++j)
        sum += get(i, j);
    return sum;
}

int Problem::rowSum(size_t j) const {
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_width; ++i)
        sum += get(i, j);
    return sum;
}

// solves column-wise using backtracking
bool Problem::solve(size_t i, size_t j) {
    size_t width = m_width, height = m_height;

    // past last column?
    if(i >= width) {
        // found solution
        return true;
    }

    // remainder in column and row
    int remColSum = a(i) - colSum(i);
    int remRowSum = b(j) - rowSum(j);
    // early break
    if(remColSum <= 0 || remRowSum <= 0)
        return false;

    // starting at the minimal required value (1 or remColSum if on last row)
    int startValue = j + 1 < height ? 1 : remColSum;
    // remaining row sum cannot support the starting value
    if(remRowSum < startValue)
        return false;
    // end value minimum remaining sum
    int endValue = remColSum < remRowSum ? remColSum : remRowSum;
    // on last element must equal starting value
    if(i + 1 == width && j + 1 == height && startValue != endValue)
        return false;

    // column-wise i.e. next cell is (i, j + 1) wrapped
    int nextI = i + (j + 1) / height;
    int nextJ = (j + 1) % height;
    for(int value = startValue; value <= endValue; ++value) {
        bool valid = true;
        // check row up to i
        for(size_t u = 0; u < i && valid; ++u)
            valid = (get(u, j) != value);
        // check column up to j
        for(size_t v = 0; v < j && valid; ++v)
            valid = (get(i, v) != value);
        if(!valid) {
            // value is invalid in partially filled table
            continue;
        }

        // value produces a valid, partially filled table, now try recursing
        set(i, j, value);
        // upon first solution break
        if(solve(nextI, nextJ))
            return true;
    }

    // upon failure backtrack
    set(i, j, 0);
    return false;
}

int Problem::operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
    return get(i, j);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 10, 3, 3 };
    int b[] = { 9, 7 };
    size_t width = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    size_t height = sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b);
    Problem problem(a, a + width, b, b + height);
    if(!problem.Solve()) {
        std::cout << "No solution" << std::endl;
    }

    for(size_t j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        if(j == 0) {
            std::cout << " ";
            for(size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
                std::cout << "  " << a[i];
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << b[j];
        for(size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
            int value = problem(i, j);
            if(value == 0)
                std::cout << "   ";
            else
                std::cout << "  " << value;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want!